# On Question Bans

Tags: discussion, post-ban

First off, I want to make it clear that I am not asking for it to be lifted, I know that won't happen. I just want to know if there is anything else can do. I cannot fix my questions, because I have done it, or they are closed, and it is extremely difficult for me to give good answers because most Questions I see that have not been answered I also cannot answer. So again, is there anything else I can do to work towards lifting the ban? I made my mistakes months ago, and I have learned to do my research before bothering with useless questions.

Comment: Closed questions can still be improved (and if sufficient improved reopened)

Comment: Welcome to the supreme court of justice, Meta! (seriously, those on the edge can come here for a pardon - sometimes it works)

Comment: Btw do you have deleted questions?

Comment: Your account does not appear to be question blocked any longer.

Comment: Your account was unblocked a few minutes ago.  You should still  keep making improvements though, as you are right on the edge of the ban threshold now.

Comment: @TinyTim Meta effect or your doing?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I understand what you mean, but besides the Meta-Effect (which can backfire) I fail to see what we can do in such a case. There is everything in that FAQ-entry...or has the rule that nobody can lift the ban changed? A request for mercy would be better send via the contact form.

Comment: @Time about "nobody can lift the ban" only Tim or other dev/manager can answer. Contact form is one way, true, and I guess many are doing this. Yet again, only staff member can say for sure. My first comment was due to seeing several cases of banned users who were on the edge, came here to Meta and got unbanned. (as for how, read the beginning of this comment ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes.

Comment: A recent and interesting case, nice info over there: [I didn't RTFM; How can I repent for my SE sins?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211304/)