# Question Ban Not Unlocked

Tags: discussion, post-ban

In my recent post, [On Question Bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212380/on-question-bans), User Bill the Lizard (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard), stated that I had been unlocked. However, I was about to ask my question when I got the question ban message again. Am I un-banned or not?

Comment: You were probably on the edge and got another downvote.

Comment: Yep. What @juergend said. I gave you 1 upvote to get you back out. Be careful out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were indeed banned - probably got another downvote. I upvoted one of your better questions and you are unbanned now.

**Be very careful!** A single downvote or closed question will most likely get you banned again!